# How to cast from AnyObject to the dynamic type?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scenario where I've to cast an AnyObject to a dynamic type (available only at runtime). Is this possible with Swift? If yes, how would I do it?

To explain the scenario further, I have a function which has a completion block that returns the response or error from a service call. In the block, the success object is in fact an Array of AnyObject where the dynamicType of the object is that of the calling class.

```
    someObject.callService(classObject, withCompletionBlock: {(objectOrNil : [AnyObject]!, errorOrNil:NSError?) -> Void in
                if(errorOrNil != nil) {                        self.delegate.didFailWithError(errorOrNil)
                }
                else {
                   // Here objectOrNil is during runTime an Array of class X 
                   // X.response gives the response JSON
                   // In a particular scenario, I need to intercept the response before the delegate
                    self.delegate.didReceiveResponse(objectOrNil)
                }

                }, withProgressBlock: nil)
```

In the block objectOrNil is an array of a class X ([X]) where the X would be class invoking the service call. All the classes that call the method has a response dictionary object which is populated with the response after the service call is completed and the delegate invoked.

To handle a particular scenario, I need to intercept the service response (X.response) where X is objectOrNil[0] from within this block and do additional processing.

I'm able to see the class name when I do a

```
po objectOrNil[0].dynamicType
```

in the console, but am unable to cast the objectOrNil[0] to the right type X to fetch X.response. When I tried

```
po objectOrNil[0].response
```

I'm getting an error that response is ambiguous with NSURLResponse response. But

```
po objectOrNil[0].response as NSDictionary
```

returns the right JSON response in console during runtime (with breakpoint).

However the below code gives a compile time error that AnyObject does not have response attribute.

```
let responseDict = objectOrNil[0].response as NSDictionary
```

Can anyone guide me on how to cast to the dynamicType type and fetch the response dictionary for me to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt compiler can foresee all kinds of scenarios and types and generate safe code. However you could define a protocol and force-cast AnyObject to it. The answer below should be marked correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a protocol

```
protocol Respondable {
  var response : NSDictionary {get}
}
```

and then constrain the type of `objectOrNil` to that protocol

```
someObject.callService(classObject, withCompletionBlock: {(objectOrNil : [Respondable]!, errorOrNil:NSError?) -> Void
```